# How To Create A ProgressBar With Spacing From The Edges In BootStrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a progress bar with some spacing from the edges of the bar. Following picture is what I am trying to create:

[image]

In The Above image there is a red line in the gray progress bar which Is what I am trying to create.

How can I recreate this using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

try to add some margin like `margin-left: 5%` to the progress-bar

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%; margin-left: 5%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 5%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%; margin-left: 5%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress mt-3">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 5%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```